# Is there a FICS android app?

Tags: software, online-chess, online, websites, android

I tried using [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jwtc.android.chess) but when I try to play online it keeps saying `game over, draw` something like that, the message will be on the screen forever unless I restart my phone. and it doesn't let me play online.

Is there a better app to play FICS on Android?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KimOx.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0EOc.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Mobialia Chess Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alonsoruibal.chessdroid.lite) includes an FICS interface; it supports premove and interfacing directly with the console.

Comment: Yes Mobialia is the best app to play FICS online games. Aside from its easy and smooth piece control. The app also support 3D view of chess.

Answer (score 2):

[Acid Ape Chess](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.acideapestudios.acidapechess&hl=en). I think it is the best in history of Android chess.

Comment: I don't know why this answer get's downvotes. He is right. Acid Ape Chess is totally free, without adds, can do fics as well as single player chess and has a nice interface. What do you want more?

Answer (score 1):

I like Mobialia chess mentioned by @Istvan Chung. It has decent support for most common uses of FICS.

The following are additional options. I have all of them since each of them provide unique advantage over the other based on what you are trying to do:

1. [Chess](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jwtc.android.chess) by Jeroen Carolus is a hidden gem. There are lots of features meant for FICS including custom commands.
2. [Yafi](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.mg6.yafi) is also worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

Mobialia is very good. My only quibble with it is that there are a fixed set of themes without a color chooser. The predefined colors look washed out and blurry on my tablet. Yafi is pretty good, but has the critical annoyance of having to go back to the console for most game management tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Also yafi is a great app for FICS. It supports the console, different game-types, observation ... most of the features you might need in a chess program.
free: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.mg6.yafi&hl=de
to buy: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.mg6.yafi.plus

Answer (score 0):

Another app supporting FICS is https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=game.android.chess. It's free and easy to use. You can challenge players, play tournaments or watch others playing a game.